# I am unable to load jquery pages for chinese customers although i have placed the .js files in my static resource, without going thru googleapis.com

Tags: community

I am unable to load jquery pages for chinese customers although i have placed the .js files in my static resource, without going thru googleapis.com ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code for the Visualforce page? Or at least the part where you include jquery? Also, is this in a Community? You have tagged the question as communities, but not mentioned it in the question.

Comment: yes, this is in salesforce communities ..

script->
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryResource, 'js/jquery.js')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPageButtonStaticDisabled = "paginate_button_disabled";
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQueryMethod();
});
function jQueryMethod(){
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$('table.casedataTable').dataTable({
   
   ******* code********         
        }
});